# Symfony, check if the user has accepted new T&C

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I need to check if the user has accepted the latest privacy policy, before executing any controller. Something like this:

```
if($user->getAcceptedTnc() < 2) // unless I'm in some specific routes...
{
    return $this->render('app/privacyPolicy.html.twig');

    // or alternatively do AppController::privacyPolicyAction()
}
```

Where can this be done?
I've thought at logging out all the users and putting this in some authentication listener...

Comment: Yes, you can add that in your AuthenticationSuccessHandler or AuthenticationListener

Comment: How can I pause the authentication until the terms have been accepted? I also need to let them delete the account, in this state

Comment: Do you want to execute the check function only when a user tries to login? Or do you want to execute it on every page before any other actions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved with a onKernelController listener, so I'm doing the check at every page load:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    // [ return on some conditions (ajax calls, specific controller/routes, ...) ]

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->token ? $this->token->getUser() : null;

    if($user && $user !== 'anon.' && $user->getLastAcceptedTerms() < Utils::CURRENT_TERMS_VERSION) {

        // [ return if the user is non-EU, has specific roles, etc...]

        // The user must accept the new Terms. Show him AppController:privacyPolicyAction
        $request = new Request();
        $request->attributes->set('_controller', 'App\Controller\AppController:privacyPolicyAction');
        $event->setController($this->controllerResolver->getController($request));
    }
}
```